# What is the difference between openjdk-7-jre-headless and openjdk-7-jre(jdk)?

Tags: java, ubuntu, headless

When I type for **java -version** in command prompt in ubuntu I get following output

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

I get above output as I do not have java install. I want to know difference between **openjdk-7-jre-headless** and **openjdk-7-jre**

Answer (score 45):

To quote [debian's wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Java/):

> There are several virtual packages used in Debian for Java. These cover runtime compatibility and come in two flavours; headless (omits graphical interfaces) and normal.

Or to be more exact, consider [this description from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html):

> *Headless* mode is a system configuration in which the display device, keyboard, or mouse is lacking. Sounds unexpected, but actually you can perform different operations in this mode, even with graphic data.

Answer (score 28):

As reported in [this blog](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-openjdk-7-jre-headless-and-openjdk-7-jre-jdk)

> Headless is the same version than the latter without the support of
>   keyboard, mouse and display systems. Hence it has less dependencies
>   and it makes it more suitable for server application.

Answer (score 14):

To add to previous answers the normal java depends on the headless and install some extra packages.

I tried to compare dependencies of:

- java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.191.b12-0.el7_5.x86_64
- java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-0.el7_5.x86_64

The comparison done with `yum install` on Centos 7.6

The normal Java (in contrast to headless) installed following extras:

```
=============================|========|=========================|============|=======|=================|
 Package                     | Arch   | Version                 | Repository |  Size | Vulnerabilities |
=============================|========|=========================|============|=======|=================|
 alsa-lib                    | x86_64 | 1.1.6-2.el7             | centos_7.6 | 424 k | 1 | 2005        |
 dejavu-fonts-common         | noarch | 2.33-6.el7              | centos_7.6 |  64 k | - |             |
 dejavu-sans-fonts           | noarch | 2.33-6.el7              | centos_7.6 | 1.4 M | - |             |
 fontconfig                  | x86_64 | 2.13.0-4.3.el7          | centos_7.6 | 254 k | 1 | 2016        |
 fontpackages-filesystem     | noarch | 1.44-8.el7              | centos_7.6 | 9.9 k | - |             |
 giflib                      | x86_64 | 4.1.6-9.el7             | centos_7.6 |  40 k | 5 | 2018        |
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless | x86_64 | 1:1.8.0.191.b12-0.el7_5 | centos_7.6 |  32 M | ? |             |
 libICE                      | x86_64 | 1.0.9-9.el7             | centos_7.6 |  66 k | 1 | 2018        |
 libSM                       | x86_64 | 1.2.2-2.el7             | centos_7.6 |  39 k | - |             |
 libX11                      | x86_64 | 1.6.5-2.el7             | centos_7.6 | 606 k | 3 | 2013        |
 libX11-common               | noarch | 1.6.5-2.el7             | centos_7.6 | 164 k |   |             |
 libXau                      | x86_64 | 1.0.8-2.1.el7           | centos_7.6 |  29 k |   |             |
 libXcomposite               | x86_64 | 0.4.4-4.1.el7           | centos_7.6 |  22 k |   |             |
 libXext                     | x86_64 | 1.3.3-3.el7             | centos_7.6 |  39 k |   |             |
 libXi                       | x86_64 | 1.7.9-1.el7             | centos_7.6 |  40 k |   |             |
 libXrender                  | x86_64 | 0.9.10-1.el7            | centos_7.6 |  26 k |   |             |
 libXtst                     | x86_64 | 1.2.3-1.el7             | centos_7.6 |  20 k |   |             |
 libfontenc                  | x86_64 | 1.1.3-3.el7             | centos_7.6 |  31 k |   |             |
 libxcb                      | x86_64 | 1.13-1.el7              | centos_7.6 | 214 k |   |             |
 ttmkfdir                    | x86_64 | 3.0.9-42.el7            | centos_7.6 |  48 k | - |             |
 xorg-x11-font-utils         | x86_64 | 1:7.5-21.el7            | centos_7.6 | 104 k | 1 | 2008        |
 xorg-x11-fonts-Type1        | noarch | 7.5-9.el7               | centos_7.6 | 521 k |   |             |
=============================|========|=========================|============|=======|=================|
```

Note that *java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless* is a dependency of *java-1.8.0-openjdk*.
Also note that the concrete dependencies may differ on your system.